# Check my work in this first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Question, solve (and find my mistake):
>
> $$y'(x)=(1-y(x))(1+ny(x))$$

**My work:**

$$y'(x)=(1-y(x))(1+ny(x))\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{(1-y(x))(1+ny(x))}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{(1-y(x))(1+ny(x))}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln\left|1+ny(x)\right|-\ln\left|y(x)-1\right|}{n+1}=x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left|\frac{1+ny(x)}{y(x)-1}\right|=(n+1)x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|\frac{1+ny(x)}{y(x)-1}\right|=\text{C}e^{(n+1)x}$$

So we get:

$$y(x)=\frac{\text{C}e^{(n+1)x}+1}{\text{C}e^{(n+1)x}-n},y(x)=\frac{\text{C}e^{(n+1)x}-1}{\text{C}e^{(n+1)x}+n}$$

Divide every term by $\text{C}$:

$$y(x)=\frac{e^{(n+1)x}+\frac{1}{\text{C}}}{e^{(n+1)x}-\frac{n}{\text{C}}},y(x)=\frac{e^{(n+1)x}-\frac{1}{\text{C}}}{e^{(n+1)x}+\frac{n}{\text{C}}}$$

Simplify for the arbitrary constant:

$$y(x)=\frac{e^{(n+1)x}+\text{C}}{e^{(n+1)x}+\text{C}}=1,y(x)=\frac{e^{(n+1)x}+\text{C}}{e^{(n+1)x}+\text{C}}=1$$

Comment: "Simplify for the arbitrary constant" What? How do you simplify $$\frac{e^{(n+1)x}+\frac{1}{\text{C}}}{e^{(n+1)x}-\frac{n}{\text{C}}}$$
into $$\frac{e^{(n+1)x}+\text{C}}{e^{(n+1)x}+\text{C}}\ ?$$

Comment: @Did when c is a constant, than is 1/c also a constant, thats why I did that

Comment: No problem with replacing $\frac1C$ by $C$ (provided one keeps in mind that $C=0$ is possible) but the trouble is that you replaced simultaneously both $\frac1C$ and $\frac{n}C$ by $C$. If $n\ne1$, this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake relatively early on in that
$$\frac1{(1-y)(1+ny)}=\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac1{1-y}+\frac n{1+ny}\right)$$
That also make it more problematic to solve explicitly for $y$ later on.

**EDIT**: OK, I see what my mistake was.
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dy}{(1-y)(1+ny)}&=\frac1{n+1}\int\left(\frac{1}{1-y}+\frac{n}{1+ny}\right)dy\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\left(-\ln|1-y|+\ln|1+ny|\right)=x+C_1\end{align}$$
I forgot that the factor of $n$ goes away on integration :( OK, moving forward,
$$\ln\left|\frac{1+ny}{1-y}\right|=(n+1)x+(n+1)C_1$$
$$\frac{1+ny}{1-y}=\pm e^{(n+1)C_1}e^{(n+1)x}=C_2e^{(n+1)x}$$
I was a bit distracted by what the O.P. was doing from this point on, but now I see that instead of absorbing the uncertainty in sign into a new constant, he was maintaining a positive constant and introducing two separate cases. The most basic mistake that was being made was perhaps to use the same symbol $C$ for different things in the same derivation. He got to
$$1+ny=C_2e^{(n+1)x}(1-y)$$
$$\left(C_2e^{(n+1)x}+n\right)y=C_2e^{(n+1)x}-1$$
$$y=\frac{C_2e^{(n+1)x}-1}{C_2e^{(n+1)x}+n}$$
And then
$$y=\frac{e^{(n+1)x}-\frac1{C_2}}{e^{(n+1)x}+\frac n{C_2}}$$
And then renamed the constant into $C$, but at this stage two different things were being renamed, $\frac{-1}{C_2}$ and $\frac n{C_2}$ to same thing in the same expression and this is where the error occurred. Being loose about $C$ throughout seems to be the cause of the O.P.'s error. I can't figure out the cause of my error: not differentiating to check the O.P.'s results due to sloth and indolence or just the decreptitude of infirmity.

Comment: Sorry but everything is correct at least until the much later step $$\left|\frac{1+ny(x)}{y(x)-1}\right|=\text{C}e^{(n+1)x}.$$

Comment: @Did: thanks for the correction. Yep, I really blew it there.

Comment: I checked my answer $1$ in the ODE and it is indeed a solution for the ODE

Comment: Sometimes you get a blind spot and it's hard to fix. One more common example of being loose with constants is: Let
$$I=\int\tan x\sec^2x\,dx$$
Integrate by parts with $u=\tan x,\,du=\sec^2x\,dx,\,dv=\sec^2x\,dx,\,v=\tan x$. Then
$$I=uv-\int v\,du=\tan^2x-\int\tan x\sec^2x\,dx=\tan^2x-I=\frac12\tan^2x$$
Upon solving for $I$. Repeat with $u=\sec x,\,du=\tan x\sec x\,dx,\,dv=\tan x\sec x\,dx,\,v=\sec x$. Then
$$I=uv-\int v\,du=\sec^2x-\int\tan x\sec^2x\,dx=\sec^2x-I=\frac12\sec^2x$$
So it looks like we have proved that $\tan^2x=\sec^2x$, but we were just loose with constants of integration.